# Unable to persist data from a Dremio Docker container using volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, persist, dremio

I am able to get a working instance of Dremio on Docker, but, I would like to persist the data on the container on my local.

I tried the approach mentioned in [this post](https://community.dremio.com/t/path-opt-dremio-data-is-not-writable-when-try-to-run-persist-dremio-docker/3790), and crafted my own version of the docker run query, but upon running the following:

```
docker run --rm -v "/home/ubuntu/dremio/data/lib:/var/lib/dremio" -v "/home/ubuntu/dremio/data/localFiles:/localFiles" -v "/home/ubuntu/dremio/data/:/opt/dremio/data" -p 9047:9047 -p 31010:31010 -p 45678:45678 dremio/dremio-oss
```

It shows the following error when run in non-detached mode:

> Dremio is exiting. Failure while starting services.
> java.io.IOException: path /opt/dremio/data is not writable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command with sudo, probably you don't have the privileges to execute this.

Comment: Tried running with that as well, didn't change anything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using the following Docker Compose file - docker-compose.yml - I was able to persist data from a Dremio container:

```
version: '3'

services:
  dremio:
    image: dremio/dremio-oss
    hostname: dremio
    volumes:
      - /absolute-path/dremio/data:/opt/dremio/data
      - /absolute-path/dremio/lib:/var/lib/dremio
      - /absolute-path/dremio/local:/localFiles
    ports:
      - "9047:9047"   # Web UI (HTTP)
      - "31010:31010" # ODBC/JDBC clients
      - "32010:32010" # Apache Arrow Flight clients
```

I launched Dremio using the 'docker-compose up' command.